# symfony2 set a refresh button

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Can i implement a refresh button in twig template that will reload my entity data on click ?

Here is my controller :

```
public function indexAction() {       

    $repositoryForHistory = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("PagesBundle:histories");

    $histories = $repositoryForHistory->findBy(Array(), Array('date' => 'DESC'));

    return $this->render('PagesBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(                    
                'histories' => $histories));
}
```

}

And the div i want to reload :

```
  <tbody>
          {% for history in histories %}
               <tr>
                  <td class="center" style="color: #ADADAD;">                 

                      <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>

                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <span class="bold-text text-small">{{history.user}} {{history.action}} {{history.featureName}}</span>
                     </td>
                     <td class="center" style="color: #ADADAD;">{{history.date|date('d-m-Y H:i')}}</td>

             </tr>
                {% endfor %} </tbody>



<a class="panel-refresh" href="#">  <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <span>Refresh</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys @Alex and @Blowski here is the solution :

in my Controller

```
   function reloadHistoryAction() {
    $repositoryForHistory = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("PagesBundle:histories");

    $histories = $repositoryForHistory->findBy(Array(), Array('date' => 'DESC'));
    $html="";
    foreach ($histories as $history) {
        $html .="<tr>
                   <td class='center' style='color: #ADADAD;'>                            
                     <i class='fa fa-tasks'></i>                        
                    </td>
                   <td>
                     <span class='bold-text text-small'>".$history->getUser()." ".$history->getAction()." ".
                $history->getFeatureName()."
                      </span>
                   </td>
                   <td class='center' style='color: #ADADAD;'>
                  ". $history->getDate()->format('d-m-Y  H:i')."
                   </td>

             </tr> ";

    }
    return new Response($html);
}
```

And in my twig template an ajax call to the controller action :

```
  $('.panel-refresh').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{path('history/reload')}}',
            type: "POST",
            cache: "false",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("tbody").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax request and send it by clicking on Refresh button, and on success just replace html of the element you want to update (actually there is no div in your template and I don't understand exactly what do you mean by div).

So, for this you have to create a special controller action which will return a poor html without layout.

It's the simplest way.

Also you can take a look at angularjs. But in some sense it might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: AngularJS - A bit more complicated? o_O

Comment: For someone might be, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something with AJAX, so that when somebody clicks the 'refresh button' it makes an XMLHttpRequest to Symfony, which returns a response that contains only the `<tr>`s (**not** the wrapping table, or the `<head>`, etc).

In jQuery (you didn't say you were using it, but the JavaScript is more complicated to write):

```
$('.panel-refresh').click( function(event, ui) {

    // prevents the browser following the click
    event.preventDefault(); 

    // replaces the contents of `<tbody>` with the response from the controller
    $('tbody').load('/path/to/action');

}
```

and replace `'/path/to/action'` with the actual path to the action.